# Force Typescript generic parameters (a: T, B: T) to be of the same type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given:

```
function sorter<T extends string | number> () {
  const icf = new Intl.Collator().compare
  return (a: T, b: T) => typeof a === 'number' ? a - b : icf(a, b)
}
```

We get a Typescript type error:

[image: typescript error]

We know that if `a` is a number then `b` will also be a number, and similarly if `a` is a string then `b` will also be a string.  This information is *not* known by the function calling `sorter` i.e. only at the time the function being returned is called.  By design we never expect to get heterogeneous items.

What options are there to assert these types correctly?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKA9AVBoAQTADAhgmSB2ATRAjVSAnAUxgBcALEgZyQFsTSBPABxIEsA6IjmNgM0QpeVNDHQBXWjiIEyldLlQB3NgBtVMaaIlSZHWBDCgiAD2YB7AqRh9x6AMak25hVUukZAHgAqMUx6wRKlICNnQAcxgAHzFJaQIAPhgAClVzeyRVIgAuGGDQiIBKGABvWBh7F2DeewEAXjEiJRgASXRSVQ4AYXN1JFJLVPTMokKOStpmQiJy4lJxAgVkpFzvABpNVeK6pKZWcwEkGDqTmAByHXizmAB+UQBaTRhctlrljZxC0ABfUCA)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
type T = number | string;

function numSorter(a: number, b: number){
  return a - b;
}

function stringSorter(a: string, b: string, locale: string) {
  const icf = new Intl.Collator(locale).compare;
  return icf(a,b)
}

function picker(a: T, b: T, locale: string) {
  if (typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number') {
    return numSorter(a,b);
  } else if (typeof a === 'string' && typeof b === 'string') {
    return stringSorter(a,b, locale);
  } else {
    throw Error("incompatible types");
  }
}

function sorter(locale: string) {
  return (a:T, b:T) => picker(a,b,locale);
}

const mySorter = sorter("US");

console.log(mySorter(1,2)); //both numbers, so ok
console.log(mySorter("world","hello")); // both strings, so ok
console.log(mySorter(1,"hello")); // incompatible types
```

Which gives an output like this:

[image]

I could be mistaken, but I think that this kind of approach defeats the purpose of static type checking. The generic reference still has to have a concrete implementation.

In this case, the operations you are performing are different for the different types `number` and `string`, so theres no overlap. The generic approach might be useful for objects that do have some overlap in functionality, like a common method they both have, like if you wanted a helper method for finding length of an array (as shown in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)):

```
function loggingIdentity<Type>(arg: Array<Type>): Array<Type> {
  console.log(arg.length); // Array has a .length, so no more error
  return arg;
}
```

This generic function will work for any array of any type, because any array has the `length` property.

Overall, I don't think its useful for this case, I think it might be better to have concrete implementations from the start, and calling the correct sorting function when needed. Generics are a bit of a headache to be honest, especially in TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the restriction on the generic type `T extends string | number` does not enforce `a` and `b` having the same *primitive* type in `(a: T, b: T) => ...`. One can be a string and the other a number, if `T` is itself the union type `string | number`.

For example:

```
// this compiles fine, even though the parameters have different types
const a: number | string = 2;
const b: number | string = '2';
sorter("en-us")(a, b);
```

Further, you've made the `sorter` function generic, meaning that the type of the comparator function's parameters is chosen at the point in time where `sorter` is called. In reality, it should be chosen by the caller of *the function returned by `sorter()`*. If we make this anonymous function generic by returning `<T,>(a: T, b: T) => typeof ...` we run into the same issue: this permits the caller to choose `string | number` for the type `T` and pass in a string and a number for comparison.

It is a bit ugly, but we can get the desired behaviour by instead returning a function that has declared overloads only for `(string, string) => number` and `(number, number) => number`. We need a single type assertion, but it is due only to a limitation of type inference in function overloads:

```
export function sorter(locale: string) {
  const icf = new Intl.Collator(locale).compare

  function comp(a: number, b: number): number;
  function comp(a: string, b: string): number;
  function comp(a: number | string, b: number | string) : number {
    if (typeof a === "number") {
      // assertion needed here: TS can't infer one param's type from another's via
      // their relationship in overloads
      // (but it is safe: this fn can only be called via a declared overload)
      return a - (b as number);
    } else {
      return icf(a, b as string);
    }
  }

  return comp;
}
```